# What is the most efficient way to concatenate strings in Dart?

Tags: dart

Languages like Java, let you concatenate Strings using '+" operator.

But as strings are immutable, they advise one to use StringBuilder for efficiency if one is going to repeatedly concatenate a string.

What is the most efficient way to concatenate Strings in Dart ?

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.1/dart-core/StringBuffer-class.html

```
StringBuffer can be used for concatenating strings efficiently.

Allows for the incremental building of a string using write*() methods. The strings are concatenated to a single string only when toString is called.
```

It appears that if one uses StringBuffer, one is postponing the performance hit till toString is called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I understood:

It appears that performance will vary depending on your use case. If you use StringBuffer, and intend to concatenate a very large string, then as the concatenation occurs only when you call toString, it is at that point where you get the "performance hit".

But if you use "+", then each time you call "+" there is a performance hit. As strings are immutable, each time you concatenate two strings you are creating a new object which needs to be garbage collected.

Hence the answer seems to be to **test** for your situation, and determine which option makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of ways to concatenate strings:

- `String.operator +`: `string1 + string2`. This is the most straightforward.  However, if you need to concatenate a lot of strings, using `+` repeatedly will create a lot of temporary objects, which is inefficient. (Also note that unlike other concatenation methods, `+` will throw an exception if either argument is `null`.)
- String interpolation: `'$string1$string2'`.  If you need to concatenate a *fixed* number of strings that are known in advance (such that you can use a single interpolating string), I would expect this to be reasonably efficient.  If you need to incrementally build a string, however, this would have the same inefficiency as `+`.
- `StringBuffer`.  This is efficient if you need to concatenate a lot of strings.
- [`Iterable.join`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Iterable/join.html): `[string1, string2].join()`.  This internally uses a `StringBuffer` so would be equivalent.

If you need to concatenate a small, fixed number of strings, I would use string interpolation.  It's usually more readable than using `+`, especially if there are string literals involved.  Using `StringBuffer` in such cases would add some unnecessary overhead.

Comment: Not all implementations of `StringBuffer` use `Iterable.join`. When compiling to JavaScript, the `StringBuffer` just `+`'s the strings together because JavaScript optimizes for that behavior internally. I agree that interpolation for fixed concatenations and `StringBuffer` for variable concatenations is the way to go.

Comment: @lrn Did you mean that not all implementations of `Iterable.join` use `StringBuffer` (and `Iterable.join` might use `+`)? (I went by the implementation shown by the [`Iterable.join` dartdoc](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Iterable/join.html).)

Comment: My bad, I misread you as saying that `StringBuffer` uses `Iterable.join` internally (which it could have been doing, but actually doesn't).